# maven cannot find dependencies even in local repository

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I have just moved to a new machine and installed a new maven (version 3) but it keeps complaining about project dependencies even though I can see them in the repository myself and all the repository declarations in pom.xml are correct. i can paste their url in the browser and they resolve fine. Some are even in the .m2 folder.

most of the ones it complain about are those from jboss

```
        <repository>
        <id>jboss-repository</id>
        <name>Jboss Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
```

any ideas?
Tx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL is not correct. It should be

`http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/`